# More efficient way to skip columns in csv to namedtuple function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm downloading a master data table from Bloomberg's Open Symbology. The csv has columns that I'm not interested in.

**Question**

Is there an efficient/Pythonic way to produce namedtuple instances from a subset of the columns found within a csv file?

**What I've tried**

My current process (Python 3.3 code below) is as follows:

1. Create a TempRecord namedtuple with all columns in the csv.
2. Create a TempRecord instance for each record in the csv file.
3. Create a BSYMRecord (with fewer and renamed attributes) from a given TempRecord.
4. Yield BSYMRecord.

This smells really inefficient.

```
from csv import reader
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import date
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from zipfile import ZipFile


def bsym_records(sector, security_type, file_date):
    """Yield BSYMRecord for given sector and security type."""
    template = 'http://bdn-ak.bloomberg.com/precanned/{s}_{t}_{d}.txt.zip'
    url = template.format(s=sector, t=security_type, d=file_date)
    response = urlopen(url)
    zipfile = ZipFile(BytesIO(response.read()))
    for filename in zipfile.namelist():
        with zipfile.open(filename) as f:
            line = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
            headers = line.strip().replace(' ', '_').split('|')
            TempRecord = namedtuple('BSYMRecord', headers)
            while True:
                line = f.readline().decode('utf-8')
                if line[0] == '#':
                    break
                t = TempRecord._make(line.strip().split('|'))
                yield reduce_bsym_record(t)


BSYMRecord = namedtuple('BSYMRecord', ['name',
                                       'ticker',
                                       'pricing_source',
                                       'security_type',
                                       'market_sector',
                                       'BBGID',
                                       'BBGID_composite',
                                       'BSID',
                                       'unique_id'])


def reduce_bsym_record(record):
    """Eliminate non-essential fields."""
    return BSYMRecord._make((record.NAME,
                             record.ID_BB_SEC_NUM_DES,
                             record.FEED_SOURCE,
                             record.SECURITY_TYP,
                             record.MARKET_SECTOR_DES,
                             record.ID_BB_GLOBAL,
                             record.COMPOSITE_ID_BB_GLOBAL,
                             record.ID_BB_SEC_NUM_SRC,
                             record.ID_BB_UNIQUE))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently importing the `csv` module but not using it. If you *were* using it, you could use the [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class to create a dictionary instead of a list for each line in the file. You can construct a `namedtuple` using keyword arguments, but it doesn't ignore spurious ones. So you'll still need to filter them manually - but you can now do this with a dict comprehension, rather than a different namedtuple:

```
for line in csvfile:
    yield BSYMRecord(**{k:v for k,v in line if k in BSYMRecord._fieldnames})
```

The trick is getting the DictReader set up in the first place. It needs a file-like object that yields strings; `ZipFile.open` gives a file-like object that yields *bytes*, and can't take an encoding. The [codecs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html) module comes to the rescue here - you can get a StreamReader that transparently decodes utf8 bytes to strings for you like this:

```
import codecs
utf8 = codecs.lookup('utf8').streamreader
```

And use it like so:

```
for filename in zipfile.namelist():
    with zipfile.open(filename) as f:
        csvfile = csv.DictReader(utf8(f))
        for line in csvfile:
             yield BSYMRecord(**{k:v for k,v in line if k in BSYMRecord._fieldnames})
```

Comment: I like this. I had to add a filter to the DictReader to skip footer lines, but it worked well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `index` to select the values you want from each line based on the headers:

```
fields = ["NAME", "ID_BB_SEC_NUM_DES", ...]

# ...                       
headers = line.strip().replace(' ', '_').split('|')
indices = [headers.index(field) for field in fields)
while True:
    # ...
    line = line.strip().split('|')
    yield BSYMRecord._make((line[i] for i in indices))
```

This keeps your current protection from the order of the fields changing and single definition of the fields you want, but means that you don't have to create your `TempRecord` for each line.